# JSON Key case sensitivity issue while unmarshalling to POJO

Tags: java, c#, json, web-services, rest

I have developed a Java RESTful POST service that consumes and returns JSON. There is a .NET consumer who generated the CS classes from the xsd I have provided. As .NET variable naming is different from Java, the keys coming in input request JSON is different from the expected JSON. Example: { "userDetail" : "sairam" } is expected but we are getting { "UserDetail" : "sairam" }.

Due to this the particular input JSON not able to be unmarshalled to POJO. I do understand that I can configure ObjectMapper like:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();  
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);  
CarInfo info = objectMapper.readValue(data, CarInfo.class);
```

**But the requests coming to my services are getting unmarshalled by the annotation @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) annotation internally. Please help what is the ideal fix for this? How can I ignore the case of keys at the annotation level?**

Thanks in Advance !!

Edit: @JavaNaming annotation can be used with PropertyNamingStrategy.PascalCaseStrategy.class value. But still I am getting: "UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "UserDetail" "
Not sure where I need to add this annotation and what I am missing here

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve it by providing your own mapping to custom types via the MessageBodyReader interface. This will basically allow you to extend the JAXRS runtime easily to support your own custom entity providers. 
The following is a rough example based on your scenario.

```
@Provider
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class CarInfoReader implements MessageBodyReader<CarInfo> {
    //. . .

    @Override
    public CarInfo readFrom(Class<CarInfo> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();  
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);  
        CarInfo info = objectMapper.readValue(entityStream, CarInfo.class);
        return info;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you send me package details of all predefined classes you have mentioned please?

Comment: Did you mean the MessageBodyReader and other associated classes, they are all jax-rs api core classes, like the javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader. Add jaxrs-api and jackson as dependencies into your maven file.